# Nativescript 8.5 'env' undefined

Tags: nativescript, webpack-5, nativescript-vue

I have an application that builds successfully but crashes on launch. This project was migrated to NS 8.5 from TNS 6.5. It's relatively small, imports have been updated along with other typical issues from the migration.

The issue is this error that seems to be coming from util in node_modules.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzogF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6QCK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKGwT.png)

I have tried removing all packages that use util and I also added a polyfill plugin to webpack config. Nothing seems to be working. Any ideas would be great as I have gone through every other related question/issue I can find.